# How can I setup freqtrade + binance-proxy in docker and docker-compose to run together? Problems with networking

Tags: python, linux, bash, docker, docker-compose

Well, I'm trying to understand docker networking, because I'm having problems communicating two services (freqtrade + binance-proxy) without luck...

I created two containers for this, the proxy with a static IP. The gateways are the following ones:

```
root@DESKTOP-74LHUDF:/mnt/e/Python/freqtrade-docker# docker network inspect bot_1 | grep '"Gateway"' | head -n 1
                    "Gateway": "172.23.0.1"
root@DESKTOP-74LHUDF:/mnt/e/Python/freqtrade-docker# docker network inspect bot_2 | grep '"Gateway"' | head -n 1
                    "Gateway": "172.24.0.1"
root@DESKTOP-74LHUDF:/mnt/e/Python/freqtrade-docker# docker network inspect bot_3 | grep '"Gateway"' | head -n 1
                    "Gateway": "172.25.0.1"
root@DESKTOP-74LHUDF:/mnt/e/Python/freqtrade-docker# docker network inspect bot_4 | grep '"Gateway"' | head -n 1
                    "Gateway": "172.26.0.1"
root@DESKTOP-74LHUDF:/mnt/e/Python/freqtrade-docker# docker network inspect bot_5 | grep '"Gateway"' | head -n 1
                    "Gateway": "172.27.0.1"
root@DESKTOP-74LHUDF:/mnt/e/Python/freqtrade-docker# docker network inspect bot_6 | grep '"Gateway"' | head -n 1
                    "Gateway": "172.28.0.1"
root@DESKTOP-74LHUDF:/mnt/e/Python/freqtrade-docker# docker network inspect bot_7 | grep '"Gateway"' | head -n 1
                    "Gateway": "172.29.0.1"
root@DESKTOP-74LHUDF:/mnt/e/Python/freqtrade-docker# docker network inspect bot_8 | grep '"Gateway"' | head -n 1
                    "Gateway": "172.30.0.1"
```

The proxy has the following number: `172.x.0.2`. (Freqtrade I cannot know, continue reading and you will know why)

I can reach the internet using `docker exec -it <container_name> ping google.com`, but I cannot reach a proxy created using `binance-proxy` although I can ping it, neither I cannot `httping` it nor from the host machine or from `freqtrade` container.

I already tried several things but I cannot see where is the problem...

I used `docker inspect` and `docker network inspect`, also I tried to execute `docker exec -it ... /bin/bash` to check `ifconfig` and `iptables` without luck, `ping` works correctly:

[image: exec ping]

It's working for only the first bot, I don't know if I used a command before to enable networking (on the first bot, because it works)

I don't know why I can't ping on the docker container but at least the proxy is reaching google DNS.

Also I tried static IPs without luck because gateway was missing on the `docker inspect` command:

[image: docker inspect]

---

This is how I run it:

[image: bash file]

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cd /mnt/e/Python/freqtrade-docker/bot_2
docker run -w="/mnt/e/Python/freqtrade-docker/bot_2" -d --name proxy_2 --net bot_2 -p 8092:8092 nightshift2k/binance-proxy:latest
docker-compose up -d
```

---

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

[image: docker-compose.yml]

```yaml
---
version: '3'
services:
  freqtrade:
    image: freqtradeorg/freqtrade:stable
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: freqtrade_2
    volumes:
      - "./user_data:/freqtrade/user_data"
    # Expose api on port 8082 (localhost only)
    # Please read the https://www.freqtrade.io/en/stable/rest-api/ documentation
    # before enabling this.
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8082:8082"
      # - "0.0.0.0:8082:8082"
    networks:
          - default
    # Default command used when running `docker compose up`
    command: >
      trade
      --logfile /freqtrade/user_data/logs/freqtrade.log
      --db-url sqlite:////freqtrade/user_data/tradesv3.sqlite
      --config /freqtrade/user_data/config.json
      --strategy xxx
networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: bot_2
```

This is my docker-compose.yml for the bot... I also tried `networks`, `0.0.0.0` with `http://172.x.0.2:8092/api/v3` instead of using localhost ip (`127.0.0.1`)

---

And also I configured correctly Freqtrade config as stated [here](https://github.com/nightshift2k/binance-proxy#-example-usage-with-freqtrade):

[image: config.json]

Maybe the problem is with the proxy, but I cannot debug correctly the bot because it's ending every time it tries to connect...

[image: crashes]

(Just see what does on the status column)

This exception causes the program to crash and restart:

[image: log exception]

[image: log]

Is there any way to prevent the bot to restart every time it fails?

---

Also, what can I try more to see where is the problem? Because I have one bot working but the other ones cannot start and the config I'm using is the same. So what's going here?

I inspected the two proxy + freqtrade containers and I don't find any differences...

[configs.zip](https://github.com/freqtrade/freqtrade/files/7629432/configs.zip)

The only thing is that when I change the cctx json config to the gateway IP it's not having any problems (in this case `172.x.0.1:809x/api/v3`).

But if I do the same on the second bot, I'm having this other problem: `('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))`